# Geo cluster with pacemaker - quorum vs booth

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, drbd

I configured a geo cluster using pacemaker and DRBD.
The cluster has 3 different nodes, *each node is in a different geographic location*.
The locations are pretty close to one another and the communication between them is fast enough for our requirements (around 80MB/s).

I have one master node, one slave node and the third node is an arbitrator.
I use AWS route 53 failover DNS record to do a failover between the nodes in the different sites.

A failover will happen from the master to the slave only if the slave has a quorum, thus ensuring it has communication to the outside world.

I have read that using booth is advised to perform failover between clusters/nodes in different locations - but having a quorum between different geographic locations seems to work very well.

I want to emphasize that I don't have a cluster of clusters - it is a single cluster, with each node in a different geo-location.

My question is - do I need booth in my case? If so - why? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Booth helps in overlay cluster consisting of clusters running at different sites.

You have one single cluster and hence you should be okay with just Quorum.